# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError exception if getting large data from server

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

I am using `BufferReader` to read large json response from server and it shows below error -

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:156)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:288)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:233)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fillBuf(BufferedReader.java:145)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readChar(BufferedReader.java:263)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:253)
    at org.acra.CrashReportData.load(CrashReportData.java:321)
    at org.acra.CrashReportData.load(CrashReportData.java:261)
    at org.acra.ErrorReporter.loadCrashReport(ErrorReporter.java:984)
    at org.acra.ErrorReporter.checkAndSendReports(ErrorReporter.java:959)
    at org.acra.ErrorReporter$ReportsSenderWorker.run(ErrorReporter.java:142)
```

I have used the following code to get data from server - **Large String Data**

```
public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,List<NameValuePair> params) {
    try {           
        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent()
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        response = sb.toString();           
        //reader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();            
    }
    }
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Manifiest file in put android:largeHeap="true" in <application> tag.

Comment: Thanks for suggetion but I have already mention large heap true inside menifest but no effect..

Comment: http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/09/javalangoutofmemoryerror-permgen-space.html    Follow this link

Comment: But his solution can not be embedded with apk.. :(

Answer (score 1):

please increase the size of memmory allocation to your server.
i am using JBoss server you increase the memory size allocation of your server accordingly.
[image]

Comment: Hi piyush, thanks for suggetion , is  that server side issue?

Comment: yes you have to increase the pool size. @DipankarBaghel

Answer (score 1):

The server gives JSON string which is more than the budget of Application's Heap, and you're storing it to `StringBuilder`.

Not a good approach (IMO).

Instead of Saving it to `StringBuilder` and then making it the source of JSON parser. I suggest to use [`JsonReader`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html). 
 On this way, you can parse JSON directly from `InputStream`.

To create `JsonReader` object in your case.

```
httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
is = httpEntity.getContent()  
JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8")));
```

The parsing process can be found in the documentation of [`JsonReader`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html)

Comment: Nice suggetion will try and let you know.. thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You might get these below errors when dealing with bulk amount of data:

- **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError**
  The reason for this error is the heap size configured for the JVM is not enough and these are no memory left for further processing. In order to avoid this error, you should first do an estimation of your heap size based on amount of data your are processing. You can set the initial value of heap size with `-Xms` and maximum size with `-Xmx`

> java -Xmx2048m -Xms256m

- **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space**
  PermGen space stores the metadata about classes loaded by JVM. If you are loading a bulk amount of classes at a time and you have configured a smaller value for PermGen space, then you will receive the above error. In order to avoid this error, perform an estimation about how many classes are being loaded and configured the space. You can set the minumum value of permGen space with `-XX:PermSize` and maximum value using `-XX:MaxPermSize`

> -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

Comment: This cannot be applied when exported to APK File

Comment: Well, I wrote the answer based on the code snippet and the information given in the question. The above points are still valid for JVM java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. Based on the use case the applicability might differ however (As in this case probably).

Answer (score 0):

Don't read the file in one shot instead read it in the chunks i.e.

```
InputStream inputStream= FileInputStream(..);
OutputStream outputStream= new BufferedInputStream(..);
byte buffer[] = new byte[1024*1024];
int read;
while((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
}
```

Here you will read 1 Mb at a time, but can transfer an unlimited amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

set largeheap as true in application tag of manifest file

```
<application

    android:largeHeap="true"
     >
```